# AVPlayer playback of single channel audio stereo->mono

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-audio, avplayer

In my iPad/iPhone App I'm playing back a video using AVPlayer. The video file has a stereo audio track but I need to playback only one channel of this track in mono. Deployment target is iOS 6. How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now finally found an answer to this question - at least for deployment on iOS 6. You can easily add an **MTAudioProcessingTap** to your existing AVPlayer item and copy the selected channels samples to the other channel during your process callback function. Here is a great tutorial explaining the basics: http://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/

This is my code so far, mostly copied from the link above.

During AVPlayer setup I assign callback functions for audio processing:

```
MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;
callbacks.version = kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0;
callbacks.clientInfo = ( void *)(self);
callbacks.init = init;
callbacks.prepare = prepare;
callbacks.process = process;
callbacks.unprepare = unprepare;
callbacks.finalize = finalize;

MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap;
// The create function makes a copy of our callbacks struct
OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks,
                                          kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap);
if (err || !tap) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to create the Audio Processing Tap");
    return;
}
assert(tap);

// Assign the tap to the input parameters
audioInputParam.audioTapProcessor = tap;

// Create a new AVAudioMix and assign it to our AVPlayerItem
AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
audioMix.inputParameters = @[audioInputParam];
playerItem.audioMix = audioMix;
```

Here are the audio processing functions (actually process is the only one needed):

```
#pragma mark Audio Processing

void init(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, void *clientInfo, void **tapStorageOut) {
    NSLog(@"Initialising the Audio Tap Processor");
    *tapStorageOut = clientInfo;
}

void finalize(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap) {
    NSLog(@"Finalizing the Audio Tap Processor");
}

void prepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount maxFrames, const AudioStreamBasicDescription *processingFormat) {
    NSLog(@"Preparing the Audio Tap Processor");
}

void unprepare(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap) {
    NSLog(@"Unpreparing the Audio Tap Processor");
}

void process(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount numberFrames,
         MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags, AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut,
         CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut) {
    OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, NULL, numberFramesOut);
    if (err) NSLog(@"Error from GetSourceAudio: %ld", err);

    SIVSViewController* self = (SIVSViewController*) MTAudioProcessingTapGetStorage(tap);

    if (self.selectedChannel) {

        int channel = self.selectedChannel;

        if (channel == 0) {
            bufferListInOut->mBuffers[1].mData = bufferListInOut->mBuffers[0].mData;
        } else {
            bufferListInOut->mBuffers[0].mData = bufferListInOut->mBuffers[1].mData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, looking for a solution to play TTS sounds on one headphone channel. Your code could be helpful or do you have any tips?

Comment: Hi Ben, I just edited my answer and added my source code. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Does anyone know how you would write this in Swift. Can't seem to get it to work?

Comment: Hi, Im having problems to correclty deallocate the tap processor after the object containing it, please see my issue here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111080/correctly-deallocating-mtaudioprocessingtap-in-swift3-2-4.