# iOS: How to play a mono audio file on both channels with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, ios5, avfoundation, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I'm currently using an `AVQueuePlayer` to play mono mp3 files that are downloaded from a URL. The audio sounds fine when it plays on the speakers, but when I put on headphones, the audio only comes out on one side.

What is the simplest way to ensure that the `AVPlayer` plays mono audio files on both channels?

Answer (score 2):

As Andreas Zöllner states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742434/19679):

> You can easily add an MTAudioProcessingTap to your existing AVPlayer
>   item and copy the selected channels samples to the other channel
>   during your process callback function. Here is a great tutorial
>   explaining the basics:
>
> http://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/

The CODE:

```
NSURL *assetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"skyfall" withExtension:@"m4a"];
assert(assetURL);

// Create the AVAsset
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];
assert(asset);

// Create the AVPlayerItem
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
assert(playerItem);
```

assert([asset tracks]);
assert([[asset tracks] count]);

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
assert(self.player);

[self.player play];

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the blog (which appears to be the only form of documentation on Taps) and it looked like a possible route, but the feature was added in iOS6 and my app needs to target iOS5, so that's a bit problematic.